# JQuery Events not Firing after re-rendering Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, jquery-events

I am working on a Backbone application which is based on a dynamic template . I have a header view, a side panel view and footer view that are dynamically initialized when calling any other view. I am using i18n to have the possibility to switch languages. The Problem is, when I choose a different language and when I call the render function the JQuery events don't fire any more. The template is rendered successfully but the buttons doesn't work.

My Backbone View :

```
define([ "jquery", "backbone", "text!../../pages/header.html" ], function($,
        Backbone, headerTpl) {

    var header = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function(options) {
            this.render();
        },
        template : _.template(headerTpl),
        events : {
            "click #enBtn" : "swichToEnglish",
            "click #frBtn" : "swichToFrench"
        },
        render : function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            this.delegateEvents();
            return this;
        },
        swichToFrench : function() {//Switching to French
            if (i18n.currentLocal == 'en') {
                i18n.currentLocal = 'fr';
                this.$el.find("#frBtn").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                this.render();//Re-rendering the template
            }
        },
        swichToEnglish : function() {//Switching to English
            if (i18n.currentLocal == 'fr') {
                i18n.currentLocal = 'en';
                this.$el.find("#enBtn").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                this.$el.find("#frBtn").css("pointer-events", "none");
                this.render();//Re-rendering the template
        }
        }
    });

    return header;
});
```

The events declared in the events object works but I have external events, JQuery events that are declared in an external file .

Example of a Jquery event:

```
$('#menu_toggle').on('click',function () {
        if ($('body').hasClass('nav-md')) {
            $('body').removeClass('nav-md');
            $('body').addClass('nav-sm');
            $('.left_col').removeClass('scroll-view');
            $('.left_col').removeAttr('style');
            $('.sidebar-footer').hide();

            if ($('#sidebar-menu li').hasClass('active')) {
                $('#sidebar-menu li.active').addClass('active-sm');
                $('#sidebar-menu li.active').removeClass('active');
            }
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('nav-sm');
            $('body').addClass('nav-md');
            $('.sidebar-footer').show();

            if ($('#sidebar-menu li').hasClass('active-sm')) {
                $('#sidebar-menu li.active-sm').addClass('active');
                $('#sidebar-menu li.active-sm').removeClass('active-sm');
            }
        }
    });
```

Any Ideas how to make the JQuery events fire after re-rendering my template? Knowing that All my Jquery events are defined in an external file called custom.js that I call when I initialize my App (Require Js) Thank You.

Comment: i've never worked on a backbone app, but maybe as in HTML the events could create problems depending on where are they called. I mean in the html file you will link to the script just before the closing of `</body>` so the DOM is already created. Maybe even here you have to do this, or try with a `document.ready()`. You will change the DOM every time you reload the template. So you calls have to be made after the DOM is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the DOM changes, your will loose your event binds too..

Try with this instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu_toggle', function () {
  //...
});
```

Comment: How to bind the events to the "new" DOM ? without calling the script file again ?